# Windows bat to linux shell script translation issue

Tags: shell, batch-file

I have the following Windows batch file:

```
set url=http://localhost:20013

wsimport -keep -s . %url%/WSInicioDeSesion?wsdl
rm ws/*.class
```

When I try to make a shell script version of it, it fails. This is my shell script:

```
#!bin/sh

#here i set the path variable, not important

URL="http://localhost:20013"
wsimport -keep -s . $URL/WSInicioDeSesion?wsdl
```

However, it seems that the variable substitution is going wrong, if I try to echo: `${URL}abcd` it prints `abcd://localhost:20013`, what's going on?

Edit: Sorry i copy/pasted the second part wrong, this is how it looks like.

So i have also tried something like rm {$URL}.txt, and for my surprise it says the file 'http://localhost:20013\r.txt\r' could not be found, why does it add a carriage return for every sentense? May it be the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last edit to the question seems to have finally shed the light on the actual cause of the problem.

Your shell script has probably been saved with Windows-style line breaks, which are `\r\n`, i.e. the Carriage Return control character followed by the New Line control character. Unix world is using just `\n`. So, the value actually stored to the `URL` variable is likely not just `http://localhost:20013` but `http://localhost:20013^R` (where the `^R` stands for the Carriage Return char). That also accounts for `echo ${URL}abcd` printing out as `abcd://localhost:20013`: the CR character at the end of the `${URL}` value moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, and `abcd` simply overwrites the initial `http`.

I think if you open the script in pretty much any popular Linux text editor, you should be able to see those extra `\r` symbols as `^R`s. Well, at least, that's what I remember seeing in Midnight Commander's built-in editor and some other console editors when opening text files transferred from some Windows machines. And, of course, you should be able to remove those characters as well (which you should do in your situation to fix the problem).

Comment: You were right, i figured it out before reading this, manually wrote the script again and it worked, i was getting extra \r all the time, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I had to change from your example is the #! line to #!/bin/sh

```
#!/bin/sh

#here i set the path variable, not important

URL="http://localhost:20013/WSInicioDeSesion?wsdl"
echo ${URL}abcd
```

prints out 'http://localhost:20013/WSInicioDeSesion?wsdlabcd' for me

Comment: So that's what i thought it would happen as well, but i dont know why i get such a weird result, im running under fedora inside a virtual machine with a windows 7 host. This said, i execute the sh like this "bash nameofthefile.sh" and well thats the weird result i get.
Also i tried another line: rm ./ws/*.class, to delete all the generated class files, yet it says there's no such directory when im seeing it right from where im executing the sh file.

Comment: try `#!/bin/bash` instead. `/bin/sh` maybe or at least compatible with the old Bourne Shell, which doesn't have all the syntax features you find in ksh or bash. Good luck to all.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.
Also, i cant even do ls -l, or rm, it always says command not found, this is dumb, is there any other way i can achieve the same result without using shell script?

Answer (score 0):

`wsimport wsimport -keep -s . $URL/WSInicioDeSesion?wsdl` should probably be `wsimport -keep -s "." "${URL}"` though I can't replicate what you are doing exactly.  The `/` following a variable reference can mean that you are replacing text.  I always specify variables with the `${}` notation to avoid stuff like that.

Comment: Same result, if i write "localhost:20013" manually it works. But i have to do this in 10 more lines so changing each line manually every time i change something is not an option.